# Application crash with Qt5qml when building with VS2019

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2019

I have an application compiled with `VS2013` and Qt `5.9.6` and it is working fine. Now I want to upgrade the Qt version to `5.15.2` and compile it with `VS2019`.The build is successful, I can run the application but it always crashes at the `Qt5Qml` module.
[image]

I've debugging for a long time but still don't know why. Maybe `5.15.2`is not fully compatible with VS2019?

Update April 20, 2020:
I have a class called `ExpressionEvaluator`

```
class ExpressionEvaluator
{
    public:
        ExpressionEvaluator();
        virtual ~ExpressionEvaluator();

        bool evaluate(const QString &expression, const QVariantMap &values);

    protected:
        class ExpressionEvaluatorPrivate *d_ptr;
        Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(ExpressionEvaluator);
        int gcCounter;
};
```

This is the definition for `ExpressionEvaluatorPrivate` and `ExpressionEvaluator`

```
class ExpressionEvaluatorPrivate
{
    public:
        QJSEngine engine;
        QMutex mutex;
};

ExpressionEvaluator::ExpressionEvaluator()
    : d_ptr(new ExpressionEvaluatorPrivate()),
      gcCounter(0)
{}

ExpressionEvaluator::~ExpressionEvaluator()
{
    Q_D(ExpressionEvaluator);
    d->engine.collectGarbage();

    delete d_ptr;
}

bool ExpressionEvaluator::evaluate(const QString &expression, const QVariantMap &values)
{
    Q_D(ExpressionEvaluator);

    QMutexLocker locker(&d->mutex);
    // CRASH HERE
    for (auto it = values.begin(); it != values.end(); ++it) {
        d->engine.globalObject().setProperty(it.key(), d->engine.toScriptValue(it.value())); // <---CRASH HERE
    }

    QJSValue qjsValue = d->engine.evaluate(expression);

    bool ok = qjsValue.toBool();

    if (++gcCounter >= GC_CALL_LIMIT) {
        d->engine.collectGarbage();
        gcCounter = 0;
    }

    for (auto it = values.begin(); it != values.end(); ++it) {
        d->engine.globalObject().deleteProperty(it.key());
    }

    return ok;
}
```

Comment: Qt 5.15.2 works fine in VS. The error is not likely in Qt, but in your code. If you have undefined behaviour, it could cause your program to crash at any time. Have you tried running in debug mode, with Qt's debug files?

Comment: I also thought about that but why is it working fine with Qt 5.9.6? I was tried debugging in debug mode but every time it always crashes at Qml modules.

Comment: That seems to indicate UB. UB, by its very nature, is unpredictable. It may sometimes work, it may not.

Comment: About working fine I mean it has been working fine for a long time like several years. That why it is looks weird to me and very hard to debugging cause there is no change on code, just the Qt and compiler. By the way, thank for you comment, at least it gives me another view.

Comment: Can't help without more detail; but I'd still assume UB. That said, it's not impossible for their to be a bug in qt.

Comment: Ok I will update more details

Comment: Updated. If there any unclear, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a long time debugging with this pain in the ass. I finally found the solution to this. (But I do not clearly understand why it works :) ). I just want to post my answer here so if anyone has faced this issue like me can find a solution.

As you can see I have a function called `ExpressionEvaluator::evaluate`, this function will be involved by multithreaded. Everything is working fine with Qt `5.9.6` but when I upgraded to Qt `5.15.2` the application often crash and the stack trace is pointed to around `QJsEngine` with the line `d->engine.globalObject()`
For my research, maybe this is the issue:

- `QJsEngine` have a function called `gc` for garbage collection
- `gc` will run with the thread the owned the engine.
- Whenever another thread is trying the access `globalObject()` or any function (like `evaluate()`) of `QJsEngine` and if `gc` is called at the same time => crash

And yeah like I said before, I do not truly understand the issue but with this guess, I was able to create a solution and it works!

Here is my solution:

- I create another thread (event loop thread ) and `QJsEngine` will live in that thread (also all of its function will be executed on this thread)
- When another thread invoked `evaluate()` it will emit a signal and that signal is connected to the slot (the slot will do the work - and of course, this slot is executed in only one thread)
- This solution makes sure: `gc` and all the functions will be executed on the same thread.

P/s: Sorry if my explanation is hard to understand but this issue is kind of specific and it is stick with my application so this is the best I can do. But for the summary: `make sure all the function of QJsEngine is called in the same thread`

Comment: in the doc, it is indicated that QJSEngine is reentrant and not threadsafe. Though I share your concerns as I also have issues with QJsEngine not being thread-safe.

Comment: But the thing is why it is working fine in `5.9.6` and not in `5.15.2`?

Comment: some improvements might have deteriorated the multi-threading capability. I had issues when copying QJSValue containing functions, as they rely on a QJsEngine, it induced issues after invocating the function call (QJsValue.call) several thousands of times. I realised that the issue was due to the fact that the value was copied between threads and that was the problem. I do not know exactly why but it seems there is a bug here. After using qt for several years, it is one of the rare times I fall uppon such an issue, heads up to the maintainers.